# How to set same props to many components?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have many components, such as `<my-a>` `<my-b>` so many；every component has a prop

```js
{
  props: {
   isDetail: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false,
    }
  },
}
```

When i create a form and use my components ,i must repeat

```js
<form>
 <my-a :isDetail="detail"></my-a>
 <my-b :isDetail="detail"></my-b>
 <my-c :isDetail="detail"></my-c>
 <my-d :isDetail="detail"></my-d>
 ........
<form>
```

Do I have some methods except **Vuex** to not write `:isDetail="detail"` like this, and  components can get `isDetail` value

```js
<my-form :isDetail="detail">
 <my-a></my-a>
 <my-b></my-b>
 <my-c></my-c>
 <my-d></my-d>
 ........
</my-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all components have the same props you can try to render them using **v-for** and dynamic components like this:

```
<component v-for="comp in comps" :is="comp" :key="comp" :isDetail="detail"/>
```

```
data: {
  return {
    comps: ['my-a', 'my-b', 'my-c']
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't use v-for , such as ```my-a``` may  emit('change')  and ```my-b``` may need to change data depend on ```my-a``` 's change

Comment: depends on communication between my-a and my-b. You still can capture events like this: `<component v-for="comp in comps" :is="comp" :key="comp" :isDetail="detail" @change="onChange"/>`